# How to write an operator in exponential form?

Tags: operators

I'm trying to solve this problem.
Let be $I_0$ that executes this transformation: $$q\rightarrow-q, ~p\rightarrow-p.$$
The request is to write $I_0$ as $$exp(iA)$$ where $A$ is an Hermitian operator.
I demonstrated that the transformation is canonical and that $I_0$ is unitary, but than I'm not able to go through to solve the request.
Thank you.

Comment: How about using a harmonic oscillator, as after 1/2 a cycle both $x$ and $p$ change signs.

Comment: Are you suggesting to use the time evolution operator?

Comment: Yes --- it seems the easiest way.

Comment: What about $A = \pi \cdot Id$ ? That gives $I_0=exp(iA) =exp(i\pi)=-1$ (Id identity operator).

Comment: @FredericThomas unitaries act on operators like $U^\dagger Q U$ so if its proportional to the identity it acts trivially.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the canonical transformation
$$\tilde{\xi}=M\tilde{\eta}$$
$$\begin{pmatrix}
Q \\
P 
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 0\\
0 & -1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
q \\
p 
\end{pmatrix}$$
So that $$M=\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 0\\
0 & -1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
e^{i\pi} & 0\\
0 & e^{i\pi}\end{pmatrix}=e^{i\pi\mathbb{I}}$$
We recognize
$$A=\pi \mathbb{I}$$

Comment: The question is asking for a unitary *implementer* such that $U^\dagger p U=-p$ etc, not  for writing $-{\mathbb I}$ as an exponential.